# Can we align Rows vertically in Browse Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, television, leanback

Can we align rows of browse fragment vertically?Or do we have anything that we can use in browse fragment so that we have different columns(having multiple rows) for each category?

[image]

So as per my current implementation I am creating multiple browse fragment at run time. Each category is a new browse fragment. For doing this there are a lot of challenges in managing focus and identifying which item Id(movie) is clicked. 
I am not able move focus from category One to category two as they are different browse fragments now. If I try to override dispatchKeyEvent method then browse fragment loose its default key events handling.

So if we can have rows as column that would make things easy for me.
**This application is for TV**.
Any other ideas/suggestions for this design ,are most welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why have several fragments showing different pages? You can have just one fragment and divide the content in HTML. That will make communications between categories a lot easier.

Comment: This was the approach I have tried to make things work. Can you please elaborate your answer little bit so that I can start putting effort in that direction? All the categories and movies are dynamic

Comment: Well, either make a Java android app or an HTML/JS app. Don't make both.

Comment: This is for Java Android App only and that to for TV.